# Is there a way to expand a JFileChooser directory without a mouse

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, keylistener

Using a JFileChooser, I can select a directory by double clicking the directory (going down a level) with my mouse.  Is there a way to select a directory without the mouse?  For example, is there a key binding to go down a directory level or do I have to somehow add a key listener to the  JFileChooser?

Comment: I'm not sure what the advantage would be? If you launch the webstart application [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html), you'll notice that you can navigate to the pane with the directories/files using "tab", and then navigate the directories/files using the "arrows", and then pressing "enter" to go down a level.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use tab to move between the different parts of the chooser, and then use the arrow keys to change which directory is highlighted, and then press Enter to change the directory to the highlighted one.

I have tested the following example code on my machine (Vista/JDK 1.6) and it works as I would expect:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      (new JFileChooser("")).showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
      System.out.println("OK!");
   }
}
```

If your project is not responding similiarly in your JFileChooser, I would debug as follows:

1. Create test.java with only the code necessary to pop up a chooser.
2. If the test app differently than within your app, its something in your code causing it to fail, such as UI skinning code, keyboard listeners, etc. Modify the example, one change at a time to closer replicate your settings for your chooser in your app and see if you can pinpoint where it breaks.
3. If even a basic test app doesn't work right, it is probably something about your setup, such as a bug in your JDK version, your OS, etc. Troubleshoot your setup.

Comment: I've tried both space bar and enter key but neither work.  But it helps knowing it should work with enter/space bar because now I can concentrate on finding out why its not working.

Comment: What version of java are you using? Is it recent? Some older versions have bugs in the jfilechooser ui (eg, see: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4922507). I will edit my answer to explain better.

Comment: I'm am using com.incors.plaf.alloy.AlloyLookAndFeel; when I change to com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel it works. I guess AlloyLookAndFeel is having jFileChooser issues.

Comment: Looking at Incors' website, the AlloyLookAndFeel has not been updated in seven years (since 2003), and has not been tested to be compatible with JDKs newer than 1.4.2. Personally, I would suggest moving to a look and feel that is better maintained, or is at least open source so you could fix any bugs in it yourself. If you've actually purchased a license for that look and feel, I suggest you contact their customer support and see whether they will issue a bug fix or a refund.

Comment: PS..please "accept" my answer as the best answer by marking the checkbox next to my answer if you feel I have provided the best answer to your original question :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the space-bar or enter key?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ctrl+enter  key to select directory.
This behavior is happened when you set to JFileChooser file selection mode to “files and direcories”:

```
JFileChooser fileBrowser = new JFileChooser();
fileBrowser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
```